# Report Type Clean-Up

Tags: reporting, custom-report-type

We are planning to do a clean-up of our report types and are looking for any recommendations/best practices around this. Could you help us with the following questions:

1. We noticed that when you create a new look up field, a new standard report type is created automatically. Is there a way to turn this feature off?
2. Is there a way to get a complete list of standard report types available in our org?
3. What is the best way to get a list of used and unused report types?
4. What is the most effective way of hiding unused report types?
5. How can we easily get a list of duplicate report types (Meaning same object/order is used )?
6. If there are duplicate report types, how can we tell if there are difference in terms of available columns/fields?

Comment: Standard report type(or any other Standard object, feature) you will not be able delete. You can delete custom report types.

Comment: I heard i can hide it using new spring 14 feature. Sounds this is only way?

Answer (score 3):

Ok, you can Hide the Report type but not delete if its standard report type. To hide report type go to Reports Tab-> Create new Report and use check box "Select Report Types to Hide" to show/hide reports you want users to see.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You wouldn't want to remove that feature, if you're making a lookup field, you more than likely will want to report on it sometime, and you wouldn't want to have to make a custom report type every time.

Create a custom report type using report as the main object, this will include report type as one of the fields on the report object. For some reason, Salesforce decided that the standard report type would not include this field. This should allow you to at least create a list of used report types, then remove any report types which are not on the list.

Comment: how about getting the list of standart report
type. i need this list to notify our client that
we will hide all this unused STANDARD
report type using the new spring 14 feature

Comment: This would give you a list of standard and custom report types. How many custom report types do they have?

Comment: i do understand creating report on report will show me list of used custom and standard report type however im also concern in GETTING THE LIST OF UNUSED CUSTOM AND STANDARD REPORT TYPE. is there a faster way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you still need help, but the Force.com IDE can come in handy here. you can export custom report types to filter from there, an/ or export all your reports then cross reference your report type to the previously exported list and find not only what is never used but the last time there was a report created or run using the type. The best thing to do in my experience though, check what each custom report type is called v what it is, you might find numerous CRTs that don't do what they should, and that aren't even necessary. Well worth the effort.